# sql case statement or if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I am doing a simple sql report and can not wrap my head around how to do this simple case statement . a parameter is either  1 or 0  for @risk. If there is a risk then return all of the  records with risks > 0 if there is no risk then return all the safe records > 0

```
SELECT count(b.observationid), a.NumAtRisk , a.CBICode, c.Observerid, d.CBIDescription, d.CBIcatID
FROM dbo.ObservationDetails a
JOIN dbo.Observation b
    ON a.ObservationID = b.ObservationID
join #Temp c 
    on c.Observerid = b.ObserverID
join CBI d
on a.cbiid = d.cbiID
where b.ObservationDate between @Begdate and @Enddate 


-- Parameter needs to return one or the other......................
and case when  
(@risk) = 1  then [a.NumAtRisk] > 0  
     else [a.NumSafe] > 0 

     end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
where (@risk = 1 and a.NumAtRisk > 0) or
      (@risk = 0 and a.NumSafe > 0)
```

A `case` expression is not needed.

Comment: i am trying this but i get this message "An expression of non-boolean type specified where a condition is expected. do i have my variables set to the wrong types or something.

Comment: Fixed it thank you 
had 2 where clauses. took one out and it worked.